# How to use sideNav of materialize css with react?

Tags: reactjs, materialize, sidenav

I'm developing an app with React, I want to use the sidenav component http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
Sidebar.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery___default(...)(...).sideNav is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Sidebar.js:8)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3534)
    at process (jquery.js:3602)
```

I'm so confused with the way of import components, libraries. There are a lot of them and a lot of ways to configure it.

What I've done is:

1. Create the app with

   create-react-app
2. Install materialize via npm

   npm install materialize-css@next
3. Create the react app

Here's the code I'm using:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

const Dashboard = () => <h2>Dashboard</h2>
const Survey = () => <h2>Survey</h2>
const Landing = () => <h2>Landing</h2>
const Home = () => <h2>Home</h2>

const App = () => {
    return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Sidebar />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/surveys" component={Dashboard} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
                Hi There!
            </div>
        )
}

export default App;
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Sidebar extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.sidenav').sideNav();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul id="slide-out" className="sidenav"> 
                <li><a href="#!"><i className="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
                <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "support-tools",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-alpha.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.15.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-bootstrap-sidebar": "0.0.1",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-materialize": "^1.1.2",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-sidebar": "^2.3.2",
    "react-sidenav": "^2.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I've tried use two versions of jQuery on index.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

But I can have the sidenav running. What could I do?

Comment: I got the same problem, any update?

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. Let me submit it.

Comment: I uploaded the solution.

Answer (score 9):

After many tries finally I got running the SideNav running with React:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sidebar",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-alpha.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-mdl": "^1.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <title>React App</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      select{
        display: block !Important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar'

const Dashboard = () => <h2>Dashboard</h2>
const Survey = () => <h2>Survey</h2>
const Landing = () => <h2>Landing</h2>
const Home = () => <h2>Home</h2>

const App = () => {
    return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div>
                        <Sidebar />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/surveys" component={Dashboard} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
                Hi There!
            </div>
        )
}

export default App;
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";

class Sidebar extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var elem = document.querySelector(".sidenav");
        var instance = M.Sidenav.init(elem, {
            edge: "left",
            inDuration: 250
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul id="slide-out" className="sidenav">
                    <li />
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">
                            <i className="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link
                            With Icon
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!">Second Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div className="divider" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="subheader">Subheader</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a className="waves-effect" href="#!">
                            Third Link With Waves
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" className="sidenav-trigger">
                    <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Also you can checkout the project from here:

https://github.com/AndyBraveMX/react-learning/tree/master/react-sidenav-materializecss

Comment: Great solution! However it is a bit hard to see what has changed. Maybe you could improve your answer in a way that it is even more helpful for others :) 
Not that you do not need any jquery to use this solution.

Comment: Hey! I'll take into account your comment and I'll improve the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out for other users, if you are using npm, make sure you install materialize using the command listed in their documentation: **npm install materialize-css@next**

Don't forget the '**@next**' at the end.

The installed version will be something like:

"materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2"
OR
"materialize-css": "^1.0.0-alpha.4"

https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js";
```

> next initialize the sidenav

```
  componentDidMount() {
   let sidenav = document.querySelector("#slide-out");
   M.Sidenav.init(sidenav, {});
}
```

> navbar

```
   <nav>
      <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" className="sidenav-trigger">
        <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>

      <a href="#" className="brand-logo">
        Logo
      </a>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

> sidenav

```
   <ul id="slide-out" className="sidenav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

> dont forget npm install --save materialize-css@next

Answer (score 0):

Also in the functional approach instead of this fragment, given in the answer above

```
  componentDidMount() {
   let sidenav = document.querySelector("#slide-out");
   M.Sidenav.init(sidenav, {});
  }
```

use code like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
   let sidenav = document.querySelector("#slide-out");
   M.Sidenav.init(sidenav, {});
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Before:
`<a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" className="sidenav-trigger"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>`

After:
`<a data-target="mobile-demo" className="sidenav-trigger"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>`

Remove the href attribute from the `<a></a>` tag