# jQuery in React js sidenav is not working

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jsx

tried to use jQuery in one of my child component signedOutLinks in React, but have no idea how it works....

```
import $ from 'jquery'
$(document).ready(function(){$('.sidenav').(sidenav();})
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});

const SignedOutLinks = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavLink to="#" className="sidenav-trigger nav-wrapper" data-target="mobile-links">
                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
            </NavLink>
            <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signup">Signup</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signin">Login</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul className="sidenav" id="mobile-links">
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signup">Signup</NavLink>
                </li>
                <li className="waves-effect waves-light">
                    <NavLink to="/signin">Login</NavLink>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignedOutLinks;
```

> Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...)(...).sidenav is not a function

Comment: Do you have SideNav dependency installed?

Comment: i have materialize css installed, and I thought materialize included sidenav. If it not please npm me !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911593/how-to-use-sidenav-of-materialize-css-with-react#49643354

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sideNav of materialize css with react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911593/how-to-use-sidenav-of-materialize-css-with-react)

Comment: Don't use `JQuery` with `React`, try something like - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/