# Materialize CSS Fixed SideNav stay open when resize

Tags: reactjs, materialize, sidenav

I am currently using Materialize CSS for sidenav-fixed on ReactJS. I realize that when the webpage is resized, the sidenav is automatically hidden.
Is there any way to show the sidenav even when I resize the webpage?

This is what I'm working for the sidenav-fixed:

```html
<ul id="slide-out" className="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
     <li><NavLink to='/dictionary/saved'>Saved Dictionary</NavLink></li>
     <li><NavLink to='/dictionary/dropfile'>Drop Dictionary File</NavLink></li>
     <li><NavLink to='/dictionary/form'>Dictionary Add Form</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add some code and example.

Comment: Yes, I have. Sorry, this is my first time using overflow.

Comment: Look at this reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911593/how-to-use-sidenav-of-materialize-css-with-react